# How to avoid overflow-x issue with subpixels in Chrome

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-transforms

I have a container div which is position relative, and has overflow-x: auto.  An inner div is absolutely positioned and has a width of 33.3333% (one third).  This inner div slides around with animations and such for the application by way of transitioning the transform: translate3d() property.  The issue is that when I want the inner div to be in the last third (translate3d set to 200%,0,0) of the parent container, it triggers the overflow property.  I believe that this only happens in Chrome (but possibly safari as well).

HTML

```
Creates a scroll bar because of subpixels
<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2"></div>
</div>

Adjusting it slightly shows this to be the case
<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2 adjustment"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test1 {
    width: 491px;
    background: lightblue;
    height: 30px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.test2 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 15px;
    background: purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate3d(200%,0,0);
}

.adjustment {
  transform: translate3d(199%,0,0);
}
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fcyx2aou/

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?  (and the adjustment I made by going to 199% won't work, because that small gap offset will eventually be visible in some of my use cases)

Comment: I really want to help you, could you illustrate with an image or something which help us to understand a bit more what you're trying to get?

There was a time I had the same issue using the translate3d, height and overflow properties.

Comment: @CarlosBensant Was the jsfiddle link not enough?  I created this as an example that could be easily seen visually.  Basically if I have a container and then have an element inside it which should be some fraction of its width (I picked 1/3 in this example, but in my application it is variable and could be 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, etc of the parent container size.)  I am then trying to move that inner div around with translate3d into the different sizes.  So if I have a 1/3 size inner div, it would be moved around via translating X 0%, 100%, and 200% respectively. The 200% creates overflow in the parent.